# My knockout code is not updating my View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using autocomplete to add names to a dynamic list of table rows.
When I add in a new Name, a new row is created but the searchText and searchId are NOT being updated. The remove link seems to work.
So my view looks like;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SHP.Models.TrainingListEmployeesViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Bulk Training
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<form class="employeeListEditor">
    <h3>Allocate or cancel training for the selected employees</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Course Name</td>
            <td><%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrainingName) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Description (optional)</td>
            <td><%: Html.TextAreaFor(
               model => model.TrainingDescription, new { maxlength = "255", style = "width:400px;height:100px;" }) %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientEmployeeSelector) %>
    <button data-bind="click: addEmployee">Add</button>
    <%--<input type="hidden" name="numberOfEmployees" id="numberOfEmployees" value="<%:Model.EmployeeList.Count %>" />--%>
    <div id="displayEmployees" style="margin-top:10px;display: block">
        <table id="employeeDataTable" class="groupBorder">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Employee</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeEmployee">Remove</a>
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: searchId"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: searchText"></span></td>
                </tr>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Employee(id, text) {
            var self = this;
            self.searchId = id;
            self.searchText = text;
        }

        var initialData = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
        function ViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.employees = ko.observableArray(initialData.EmployeeList);
            self.searchText = ko.observable(initialData.SearchText);
            self.searchId = ko.observable(initialData.SearchTextId);
            self.removeEmployee = function(employee) {
                self.employees.remove(employee);
            };
            self.addEmployee = function() {
                self.employees.push(new Employee(self.searchId, self.searchText));
                $('#SearchText').val('');
            };
            self.save = function() {
                ko.utils.postJson(location.href, { employees: self.employees });
            };
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

And when I click the add button (which I would prefer to remove when it is working so that the add event is triggered by the return key) the following row is added to the table;

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeEmployee">Remove</a>
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: searchId" value=""/>
                    </td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: searchText"/></td>
                </tr>               
            </tbody>
```

So the remove link correct appears and it works as well. But both the searchId and searchText are NOT set. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is my second answer, taking into account antishok's valid critisisms of my first answer. The problem I was having was that I set the variable initialData to the model. However the autocomplete fields were not in the model.
So this is my solution in my script;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Employee(id, text) {
        var self = this;
        self.searchTextId = ko.observable(id);
        self.searchText = ko.observable(text);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SearchText').attr("data-bind", "value: autocompleteSearchText");
        $('#SearchTextId').attr("data-bind", "value: autocompleteSearchTextId");

        var initialData = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
        var autocompleteData = { "autocompleteSearchTextId": 0, "autocompleteSearchText": null };
        function ViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.employees = ko.observableArray(initialData.EmployeeList);
            self.autocompleteSearchText = ko.observable(autocompleteData.autocompleteSearchText);
            self.autocompleteSearchTextId = ko.observable(autocompleteData.autocompleteSearchTextId);
            self.removeEmployee = function(employee) {
                self.employees.remove(employee);
            };
            self.addEmployee = function() {
                self.employees.push(new Employee(self.autocompleteSearchTextId(), self.autocompleteSearchText()));
                self.autocompleteSearchText('');
            };
            self.save = function() {
                var trainingName = $("#TrainingName").val();
                var trainingDescription = $("#TrainingDescription").val();
                ko.utils.postJson(location.href, { employees: self.employees, trainingName: trainingName, trainingDescription: trainingDescription });
            };
        }   
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    });
</script>
```

I use JQuery to put in the databindings to the autocomplete fields, and then the observables work as they should. I learnt a lot from doing this - and maybe this is still not the best solution? But many thanks to antishok.

Answer (score 2):

When your code is calling `new Employee(self.searchId, self.searchText)`, you are passing the 2 observables as arguments. That is, you're passing the observables themselves, **not** their values. So the new Employee's properties will just be references to the main 2 observables. This is probably not what you want.

You should pass the **values** of the observables (instead of the observables themselves), like so: `new Employee(self.searchId(), self.searchText())`. This way each new employee will get a copy of the current values of the 2 main observables.

Also, in many cases it is useful to have the Employee's properties be observables themselves (e.g. if they can change).

Here's a fiddle demonstrating that: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/KXhem/73/

Edit: updated fiddle based on poster's comment with more info: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/KXhem/74/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the best answer, but credit to antishok for helping me along the way.
The actual JSON data was stored as follows;

```
{"EmployeeList":[],"ClientEmployeeSelector":{"SearchText":null,"SearchTextId":0},"Cvm":null,"TrainingName":null,"TrainingDescription":null};
```

So the SearchText and SearchTextId were nested in the ClientEmployeeSelector.
Another problem was that the observable on these fields were set correctly as zero and null, but did not update when they changed from autocomplete.
So the way I fixed it was as follows;
    
        function Employee(id, text) {
            var self = this;
            self.searchId = id.val();
            self.searchText = text.val();
        }

```
    var initialData = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.employees = ko.observableArray(initialData.EmployeeList);
        self.searchText = ko.observable($('#SearchText'));
        self.searchId = ko.observable($('#SearchTextId'));
        self.removeEmployee = function(employee) {
            self.employees.remove(employee);
        };
        self.addEmployee = function() {
            self.employees.push(new Employee(self.searchId(), self.searchText()));
            $('#SearchText').val('');
        };
        self.save = function() {
            ko.utils.postJson(location.href, { employees: self.employees });
        };
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```

Now I do not know if this is the best answer, but as far as I can tell it works.

Comment: No, this is definitely not the proper way to do it (even though it may work). Referring to specific DOM elements from your viewmodel code beats the whole KO bindings purpose. the search text itself should be the observable's value (NOT the jquery object) and the 'value' data-bind should be used like in my example fiddle. If you want to update the text (like empty it) then empty the observable, NOT the element directly. Of course, you can leave it as you did it but I'm pretty certain you'll run into problems with that soon

Comment: I thought it was too good to be true. However as I am new to knockout I am struggling with the syntax which is why I am posting on Stackoverflow in order to find out how it should be done. I have not yet ticked the right answer, so if you can help me that would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't be sure because I don't really know what functionality you're looking for, but as I said, you want your viewmodel observables to hold actual data (not DOM elements). The DOM elements have data-bindings to the viewmodel, this is what will keep them updated automatically (i.e. you don't want/need to directly update the DOM yourself). so self.searchText's value should be a string, and in the Employee constructor just use `self.searchText = text`. Instead of `$('#SearchText').val('')` do `self.searchText('')` to empty the observable's value.

Comment: I updated my fiddle with this change and with your JSON data. (the Employee's properties are observables in the fiddle, but they don't have to be if you don't need them to be)

Comment: It works in JsFiddle but not in my app. I think the issue in my app is that initialData is not being updated when I use autocomplete. As a result it is inserting empty rows.